# How should I test installation procedure on clean system (quickly and disk-space cheap)?

Tags: software-installation, virtual-machine, testing

I was asked to invent an installation procedure for existing application, including compilation, downloading and installing the server and some other things.

I have managed to get the program to work and I have documented my progress, but now I need to check that it actually will work again on clean system. I assume people who do this often must have some quick OS sandbox that allways starts clean so that they're really testing on clean system.

Obvious approach is to install another VM and work with clean-install copy every time. That's both time *and* space consuming, and please note that I have but a 140GB of disk space, some of which is already used.

So is there some system more dedicated to what I want to do? My install is targeted on Debian Linux distribution.

Comment: A VM is the way to go IMO. And 140GB is plenty of space, Debian requires just a few gigs. You can then create snapshots and restore them to go back to a well-known state. Or you could leverage LXC, e.g. Docker.

Answer (score 1):

A viable solution would be `vagrant`, a commandline frontend to virtualbox (or others) to automatically download, run and destroy VMs.

With very few commands you'll have a clean VM up and running and can test.

Comment: I'll take a look at that once I have my minimal VM ready.

Comment: The thing is that you don't even need to create the VM image yourself. Example: To fire up a clean debian VM: `vagrant box add debian/jessie64` downloads the image, `vagrant up` starts it. you can then do your testing...